# How to get the last generated value for a custom PRIMARY KEY column in ZF2?

Tags: zend-framework2, primary-key, zend-db

With `Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\ResultInterface#getGeneratedValue()` `Zend\Db` provides a simple way to get the ID of the last `INSERT`ed entry, e.g.:

```
$action = new Insert('my_table');
$action->values($data);
$sql = new Sql($this->dbAdapter);
$statement = $sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject($action);
$result = $statement->execute();
$newId = $result->getGeneratedValue();
```

But it seems only to work, if the `PRIMARY KEY` column calls "id". How to retrieve the `generatedValue` for a `PRIMARY KEY` defined on another column?

Comment: Which SQL you are using ?

Comment: MySQL. But thanks to the database abstraction layer it doesn't matter in this case.

Comment: Than getLastInsertValue(); should works fine. PostgreSQL have problem in some cases...

Comment: Word of advice: stop using autogenerated ID immediately and switch to UUIDs.

Answer (score 1):

Preferably use `Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway` offering the method [`getLastInsertValue()`](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-db/blob/master/src/TableGateway/AbstractTableGateway.php#L466).

```
use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway;
$myTable = new TableGateway('my_table', $this->dbAdapter);
$action = new Insert('my_table');
$action->values($data);
$myTable->insertWith($action);
$newId = $myTable->getLastInsertValue();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->dbAdapter->getDriver()->getLastGeneratedValue();
```